# How to save value with ng-repeat Dynamic repeater field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### Dynamic repeater field with AngularJS

I'm new to AngularJS. I have managed to generate the repeater field dynamically but I don't know how to save its value.

Repeater values come from an array in PHP. It would be something like this:

```
$repeater = [
    'name' => 'redirections',
    'title' => 'Redirection',
    'add_button_text' => 'New redirection',
    'save_button_text' => 'Save',
    'delete_button_text' => 'Remove redirection',
    'fields' => [
        [
            'name' => 'old_url',
            'type' => 'url',
            'label' => 'Old URL'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'new_url',
            'type' => 'url',
            'label' => 'New URL'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Then the info I render in HTML like this:

```
<div class="field-container repeater">
    <div class="field-wrapper" ng-repeat="(key, item) in repeaterItems">
        <div class="title" ng-click="toggleRepeater($event)">
            <span>{{ field.title }}</span>
            <span ng-repeat="input in field.fields" class="field-block">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="inputs" ng-repeat="(index, input) in field.fields">
                <label>
                    {{ input.label }}
                    <input type="{{ input.type }}" name="{{ input.name }}"
                           value="{{ input.value }}" ng-model="input.value"
                           ng-change="update_repeater_item()">
                </label>
            </div>
            <span class="delete"><span ng-click="remove_repeater_item($event)">
              {{ field.delete_button_text }}
            </span></span>
        </div>
        <input id="{{ item.id }}" class="{{ item.id }} repeater-item-value"
               type="hidden" name="{{ field.name }}[{{ item.id }}][]" value="">
    </div>

    <button class="repeater-button add-button" ng-click="add_repeater_item($event)">
      {{ field.add_button_text }}
    </button>
    <button class="repeater-button save-button" ng-click="save_repeater($event)">
      {{ field.save_button_text }}
    </button>
</div>
```

And finally, what I have about Angular is this:

```
scope.repeaterItems = [];
scope.toggleRepeater = function($event) {
    const clicked = angular.element($event.currentTarget);
    const inside = angular.element($event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);
    if (clicked.hasClass('open')) {
        clicked.removeClass('open');
        inside.removeClass('show'); // .inside
    }
    else {
        clicked.addClass('open');
        inside.addClass('show'); // .inside
    }
};

scope.add_repeater_item = function() {
    scope.repeaterItems.push({
        'id': Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2),
        'value': {}
    });
};

scope.remove_repeater_item = function($event) {
    const clicked = $event.currentTarget;
    const container = clicked.closest('.field-wrapper'); // .field-wrapper
    const inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let deletedItemId = '';
    for (let input of inputs) {
        if (input.type === 'hidden') {
            deletedItemId = input.id;
        }
    }
    scope.repeaterItems = $filter('filter')(scope.repeaterItems, {id: '!' + deletedItemId}, true);
};
```

```
scope.update_repeater_item = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};

scope.save_repeater = function($event) {
    console.log($event);    
};
```

What I get visually with this code is this (in case it helps):
[Repeater rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrD00.png)

[image]

Any help or improvement of the current code is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to save the values here. Are you trying to save them to the database? This will most likely require an AJAX request to an endpoint to save the values in the database with PHP.

Comment: What I would like is that every time a value of an input is changed within the repeater, a variable containing in an array the key => value of each input is updated.

Then I would take care of updating the db by clicking on the save button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the inputs to properties of the ng-repeat item value object:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in repeaterItems" ng-init="itemIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="input in field.fields">
        <label>
            {{ input.label }}
            <input type="{{ input.type }}" name="{{ input.name + itemIndex}}"
                   ng-model="item.value[input.name]"
                   ng-change="update_repeater_item(item, itemIndex, input.name)">
        </label>
    </div>
    <span ng-click="remove_repeater_item(itemIndex)">
      {{ field.delete_button_text }}
    </span>
</div>

<button class="add-button" ng-click="add_repeater_item()">
  {{ field.add_button_text }}
</button>
<button class="save-button" ng-click="save_repeater(repeaterItems)">
  {{ field.save_button_text }}
</button>
```

This simplifies the code:

```
$scope.repeaterItems = [];

$scope.add_repeater_item = function() {
    $scope.repeaterItems.push({
        'id': Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2),
        'value': {}
    });
};

$scope.remove_repeater_item = function(index) {
    console.log("removing", $scope.repeaterItems[index].id);
    $scope.repeaterItems.splice(index,1); 
};

scope.update_repeater_item = function(item, index, name) {
    console.log(item.id, item.value);
    console.log($scope.repeaterItems[index]);
    console.log(name + ' changed to ' + item.value[name]);
};

$scope.save_repeater = function(items) {
    console.log(items);
    $http.post(url, items);    
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I really appreciated! But I don't know why the item.value [name] returns me undefined.

Comment: Works in the [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/OT1aA4r1nGGNgZ2I3L5q?p=preview)

Comment: I have solved it. For some reason the ng-change is not going well with url type inputs but with text type.

Comment: With `<input type="url">` the ng-model controller will only fire the `ng-change` directive for valid urls.